# Check for duplicate reminder from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have some vba code that creates a reminder in my outlook calendar from data in excel. But I don't have a way of knowing if i already have the reminder in excel. I want to know if someone can help me tweak my code to show me if I already have this reminder set in outlook. The reminder will have the same exact text in the subject line.

```
Sub D_Reminders()

    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim objReminder As Object

    Set appOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set objReminder = appOL.CreateItem(1)
    objReminder.Start = ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    objReminder.Duration = 1
    objReminder.Subject = "Rate Expires for " & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    objReminder.ReminderSet = True
    objReminder.Location = "N/A"
    objReminder.busystatus = olfree
    objReminder.body = "Loan Type = " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Status = " & ActiveSheet.Range("BK" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " UW = " & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Proc = " & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " MLO = " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    objReminder.display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (2):
Hopefully this resolves the issue. Instead of checking for reminder text, we will be checking the Subject of Calendar items to see if the subject exists. If not, we add it.

```
Function AppointmentTextExists(ByRef oOtlk As Object, appointmentSubjectText As String) As Boolean
    Dim oAppt As Object
    Dim oAppts As Object
    Dim output As Boolean

    output = False

    'Get all items from the calendar
    Set oAppts = oOtlk.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items

    For Each oAppt In oAppts
        If oAppt.Subject = appointmentSubjectText Then
            output = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oAppt

    AppointmentTextExists = output
End Function

Sub D_Reminders()
    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim objReminder As Object
    Dim reminderText As String

    Set appOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")

    'The subject text for the reminder
    reminderText = "Rate Expires for " & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    'Test if this reminder text is already in a subject line
    If AppointmentTextExists(appOL, reminderText) Then
        'Do whatever you want if the subject already exists
        'You can leave this blank if you don't want to do anything
    Else 'Subject does not exist
        Set objReminder = appOL.CreateItem(1)
        objReminder.Start = ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.Duration = 1
        objReminder.Subject = "Rate Expires for " & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.ReminderSet = True
        objReminder.Location = "N/A"
        objReminder.BusyStatus = olFree
        objReminder.Body = "Loan Type = " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Status = " & ActiveSheet.Range("BK" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " UW = " & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Proc = " & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " MLO = " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.Display
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:
I've made some changes to incorporate the solution into your code. I created a separate function to contain the logic for testing whether or not a subject line already exists. See if you can piece it together from this code, or write back with more specific questions.

```
'Function that checks to see if a reminder text already exists in Outlook
'Parameters: objOutlook     - A reference to an Outlook Objet
'            reminderText   - The lookup text
'Returns:    True/False if text exists
Function DoesReminderExist(ByRef objOutlook As Object, reminderText As String) As Boolean
    Dim oRem As Object
    Dim output As Boolean

    'Initially set output to false (in case reminder text isn't found)
    output = False

    'Loop through all reminders in Outlook, and test for equality
    For Each oRem In objOutlook.Reminders
        'Reminder text matches in outlook
        If oRem.Subject = reminderText Then
            output = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oRem

    'Return T/F output
    DoesReminderExist = output
End Function

Sub D_Reminders()
    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim objReminder As Object
    Dim reminderText As String

    Set appOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")

    'The subject text for the reminder
    reminderText = "Rate Expires for " & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    'Test if this reminder text is already in a subject line
    If DoesReminderExist(appOL, reminderText) Then
        'Do whatever you want if the subject already exists
        'You can leave this blank if you don't want to do anything
    Else 'Subject does not exist
        Set objReminder = appOL.CreateItem(1)
        objReminder.Start = ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.Duration = 1
        objReminder.Subject = "Rate Expires for " & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.ReminderSet = True
        objReminder.Location = "N/A"
        objReminder.BusyStatus = olFree
        objReminder.Body = "Loan Type = " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Status = " & ActiveSheet.Range("BK" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " UW = " & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " Proc = " & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "," & " MLO = " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        objReminder.Display
    End If
End Sub
```

The code below will get the list of reminders and their corresponding texts. You can compare work it into your code to test for equality, and then ignore/update as necessary.

```
Sub GetReminders()
    Dim appOl As Object
    Dim oRem As Object

    Set appOl = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    For Each oRem In appOl.Reminders
        Debug.Print "Caption: " & oRem.Caption
    Next oRem

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not a real programmer and I don't know how to incorporate, can you help?

Comment: I am getting runtime error 438 object does not support this property or method. The debugger stops at  "If oRem.Subject = reminderText Then"

Comment: @MEC Sorry. I wrote the code without actually testing. I assumed you were working with outlook reminders (which don't have subjects), but you are actually working with appointment objects. I will amend the code

Comment: do you think you can help me with that code please?

Comment: @MEC I updated my post yesterday. I added Edit 2 at the top of my post with the latest revision. Does that work for you?

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly, I appreciate your help :-)